# How to make a Selection in D3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

How to make a selection in D3.js by using Renderer like in Highcharts? Is there is any other options to make a selection in D3.js???

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Isn't Renderer in highcharts used to draw new elements? There are plenty of examples both on how to draw and select elements on the d3.js website. Have a look at the tutorials.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XjzFH/33/   see the example which i have provided can we do the same selection to find min and max in D3.js?

Comment: I see. I'm not aware of anything like that in d3.js (except maybe brush behaviour for axes), but at least in theory there's no reason not to use both d3.js and highcharts.

Comment: did you mean selecting the dom elements using d3 ???